# How can I select from a result?

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `class_key`,(SELECT `uint_key` FROM classes_uints.`14749061566875` WHERE `type` 
= 'homeworks' LIMIT 1) AS `uint_key` FROM `14754931095281411` t1
```

that returns this result:

> class_key -------- uint_key
>
> 14788827118147 -------- 1474906156414701216
>
> 1479213957519-------- 1474906156414704452
>
> 14749061566875 -------- 1474906156414701212

I also have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `1474906156414701131` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`added_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
`added_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`max_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`homework_content` text NOT NULL,
`homework_pagenumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`add_by_user_key` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The name of the table is the result of the `uint_key => 1474906156414701131`

From each unit_key I need to get `SELECT * FROM`unit_key

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how many different unit_keys (tables) you have ?

Comment: they are unique

Comment: i edit the qustion